# Checking values row by row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables like this:

Table 1:

```
CatID  Name
-----  ----
1      A
2      B
3      C
```

Table 2:

```
ID   CatID
---  -----
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    3
```

Table two CatID is same as the table1 CatID.

I want a query which shows the First table with an additional column which says True if CatID exists in the second table or False if not. The output of the above table should be:

```
CatID  Name  Result
-----  ----  ------
1      A     True
2      B     False
3      C     True
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `CASE` and `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT CatID,
       Name,
       Result = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                                 FROM Table2 t2 
                                 WHERE t2.CatID=t1.CatId)
                THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
FROM Table1 t1
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/151df/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de4a6/2)

```
select distinct A.CARDID, NAME, CASE WHEN ISNULL(B.CARDID, 0)=0 THEN 'FALSE'
                            ELSE 'TRUE' END
FROM table1 A
LEFT JOIN table2 B
on A.CARDID = B.CARDID
```

Comment: Using `DISTINCT` here is quite expensive. You should compare your execution plan to @Tim's...

Comment: Thanks for your comments, yes @tim's query plan is better.